# ActiveRecord (without rails) create_database throws error 'database does not exist'

Tags: ruby, activerecord

For a new project I thought, why not skip rails and do more myself. Sadly I fail at a really simple problem.

I found out already that I need to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('backend')` after I set the connection with `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` to create the database.

Sadly the error I get is really annoying since it tells me it can not create the database, because it does not exist: `ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (Unknown database 'backend')`.

I use docker-compose to host the code and database, hostname/username/password are all correct.
It is har to use google since all code examples use rails and tell you to call `rake db:create` witch I obviously try to create myself while I had this error.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_record'
=> true
irb(main):002:1* ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
irb(main):003:1*   adapter: 'mysql2',
irb(main):004:1*   host: 'database',
irb(main):005:1*   username: 'root',
irb(main):006:1*   password: '',
irb(main):007:1*   database: 'backend',
irb(main):008:0> )
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x0000565044f4f638 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x0000565044f4f430>, @mon_data_owner_object_id=300, @query_cache_enabled=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000565044f4f390 entries=0 default_proc=#<Proc:0x0000565044f4f250 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:32>>, @spec=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification:0x0000565044f4fed0 @name="primary", @config={:adapter=>"mysql2", :host=>"database", :username=>"root", :password=>"", :database=>"backend"}, @adapter_method="mysql2_connection">, @checkout_timeout=5, @idle_timeout=300.0, @size=5, @thread_cached_conns=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000565044f4f160 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @connections=[], @automatic_reconnect=true, @now_connecting=0, @threads_blocking_new_connections=0, @available=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::ConnectionLeasingQueue:0x0000565044f4f020 @lock=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x0000565044f4f638 ...>, @cond=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x0000565044f4efd0 @monitor=#<Monitor:0x0000565044f4f430>, @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x0000565044f4ef30>>, @num_waiting=0, @queue=[]>, @lock_thread=false, @reaper=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Reaper:0x0000565044f4ee90 @pool=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x0000565044f4f638 ...>, @frequency=60.0>>
irb(main):009:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('backend')
Traceback (most recent call last):
       15: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
       14: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `load'
       13: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.1/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
       12: from (irb):9
       11: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:206:in `connection'
       10: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:238:in `retrieve_connection'
        9: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1121:in `retrieve_connection'
        8: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:439:in `connection'
        7: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:595:in `checkout'
        6: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:873:in `acquire_connection'
        5: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:912:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
        4: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:933:in `checkout_new_connection'
        3: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:889:in `new_connection'
        2: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `mysql2_connection'
        1: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:28:in `rescue in mysql2_connection'
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (Unknown database 'backend')
```

Two of the few good resources I found are a [gist](https://gist.github.com/schickling/6762581) and a [tutorial](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/ruby-activerecord-without-rails-tutorial) but they are not really helpful here as well.

Thanks in advance.

**Update after the answer from Apurva Mayank:**

the mysql2-gem is also in my gemfile and is also used, in the same IRB above I can call `Mysql2` without any problems.

Also if I run the following it works, but it is not using active record:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "database", :username => "root", :password => '')
client.query("CREATE DATABASE backend")
```

**Update: it gets stranger**

It seems that creating the database, then using the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`, then removing it and creating it using active record works.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_record'
=> true
irb(main):002:1* ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
irb(main):003:1*   adapter: 'mysql2',
irb(main):004:1*   host: 'database',
irb(main):005:1*   username: 'root',
irb(main):006:1*   password: '',
irb(main):007:1*   database: 'backend',
irb(main):008:0> )
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x000055f4d9b7e188 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x000055f4d9b7ddf0>, @mon_data_owner_object_id=300, @query_cache_enabled=#<Concurrent::Map:0x000055f4d9b7dd78 entries=0 default_proc=#<Proc:0x000055f4d9b7dc10 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:32>>, @spec=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification:0x000055f4d9b7f358 @name="primary", @config={:adapter=>"mysql2", :host=>"database", :username=>"root", :password=>"", :database=>"backend"}, @adapter_method="mysql2_connection">, @checkout_timeout=5, @idle_timeout=300.0, @size=5, @thread_cached_conns=#<Concurrent::Map:0x000055f4d9b7d8a0 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @connections=[], @automatic_reconnect=true, @now_connecting=0, @threads_blocking_new_connections=0, @available=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::ConnectionLeasingQueue:0x000055f4d9b7d710 @lock=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x000055f4d9b7e188 ...>, @cond=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x000055f4d9b7d530 @monitor=#<Monitor:0x000055f4d9b7ddf0>, @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x000055f4d9b7d4e0>>, @num_waiting=0, @queue=[]>, @lock_thread=false, @reaper=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Reaper:0x000055f4d9b7d288 @pool=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x000055f4d9b7e188 ...>, @frequency=60.0>>
irb(main):009:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('backend', charset: 'utf8')
=> ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (Unknown database 'backend')
irb(main):010:0> client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "database", :username => "root", :password => '')
=> #<Mysql2::Client:0x000055f4da55eb08 @read_timeout=nil, @query_options={:as=>:hash, :async=>false, :cast_booleans=>false, :symbolize_keys=>false, :database_timezone=>:local, :application_timezone=>nil, :cache_rows=>true, :connect_flags=>2148573700, :cast=>true, :default_file=>nil, :default_group=>nil, :host=>"database", :username=>"root", :password=>""}>
irb(main):011:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('backend', charset: 'utf8')
=> ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (Unknown database 'backend')
irb(main):012:0> client.query("CREATE DATABASE backend")
=> nil
irb(main):013:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('backend', charset: 'utf8')
=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Can't create database 'backend'; database exists)
irb(main):014:0> client.query("DROP DATABASE backend")
=> nil # it got removed
irb(main):015:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('backend', charset: 'utf8')
=> nil # it was created
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, thanks for your help.

On [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/rubyprogramming/2850951384992659) I got advised to use the gem [ActiveRecord-without-Rails](https://github.com/topofocus/ActiveRecord-without-Rails) which might have worked out of the box, but since I wanted to know how it works I did a deeper look before using it.
It turns out that the rake-tasks to create a database are not in Rails, but [hidden in ActiveRecord](https://github.com/topofocus/ActiveRecord-without-Rails/blob/master/Rakefile#L16).

Then looking at [how ActiveRecord creates](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb#L19) the database for Mysql in a rake task you can see that it first calls #establish_connection without the database name.

As you can see below, this is the solution. It now creates the database.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_record'
=> true
irb(main):002:1* ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
irb(main):003:1*   adapter: 'mysql2',
irb(main):004:1*   host: 'database',
irb(main):005:1*   username: 'root',
irb(main):006:0>   password: '')
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x0000555a68383c00 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x0000555a68383868>, @mon_data_owner_object_id=300, @query_cache_enabled=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000555a68383818 entries=0 default_proc=#<Proc:0x0000555a683835e8 /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:32>>, @spec=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification:0x0000555a68388340 @name="primary", @config={:adapter=>"mysql2", :host=>"database", :username=>"root", :password=>""}, @adapter_method="mysql2_connection">, @checkout_timeout=5, @idle_timeout=300.0, @size=5, @thread_cached_conns=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000555a68383598 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @connections=[], @automatic_reconnect=true, @now_connecting=0, @threads_blocking_new_connections=0, @available=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::ConnectionLeasingQueue:0x0000555a683834f8 @lock=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x0000555a68383c00 ...>, @cond=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x0000555a683834a8 @monitor=#<Monitor:0x0000555a68383868>, @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x0000555a68383480>>, @num_waiting=0, @queue=[]>, @lock_thread=false, @reaper=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool::Reaper:0x0000555a68383430 @pool=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x0000555a68383c00 ...>, @frequency=60.0>>
irb(main):007:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('backend', charset: 'utf8')
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('backend', charset: 'utf8')
=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Can't create database 'backend'; database exists)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using MySql. ActiveRecord alone will not able to perform the operations. You need an RDMS ruby client as well to communicate. I think using [mysql2](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) gem additionally should resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete question. I am using mariadb and I have the mysql2 gem in my gemfile and installed. If y write `Mysql2` in the same IRB it is loaded.

Comment: ok. Please edit the question so that it include these details. Also try to establish connection using the mysql gem.

For example;

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => 'pass')

client.query("CREATE DATABASE backend")

Comment: Thanks, I did. It works, but it is not using active record. For now, I can continue but would be great to find out why active record is not working :(

Comment: What does it says when you require 'mysql' and 'activerecord' both and then run your query

Comment: Sadly it did not help aswel